# NodeJS "npm update -g npm" fails with "Error: Refusing to delete" (Installed via package, NOT homebrew)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

While trying to fix a [JPG compatibility issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/289), I'm running into the following error when trying to update npm on my Mac OSX (Yosemite). Note that I **did not** install via homebrew, instead via the [official package](https://nodejs.org/download/). (I'm using version 0.10.37 to counteract [yet another NPM package issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/489)).

Here are the steps I take:

- `brew uninstall node` and `brew uninstall npm` to be triple-sure Node is not present on my system via Homebrew. The output is as expected, `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node`
- Download the package from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.37/ and install it.
- `node -v` to verify that Node is installed.
- `npm update -g npm`

And here's the output from that last command:

```
$ npm update -g npm
npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3 not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
File exists: /usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/topher
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3 not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! error rolling back     at clobberFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:57:12)
npm ERR! error rolling back     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:43:14)
npm ERR! error rolling back     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:52:12
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3 not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm] code: 'EEXIST', path: '/usr/local/share/man/man3/npm-bin.3' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

When I delete the above mentioned file and try again, I get another error because the `npm` command no longer exists. It looks like the update partially succeeded in that the `npm` command was deleted:

```
$ npm
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

When I search for this "Refusing to delete" error, I see tons of advice for how to fix a botched Homebrew install (plus some [unnecessarily condescending instructions on how to remove the Homebrew package](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794#issuecomment-23272631). But I'm not installing the package via homebrew; the advice I'm finding there doesn't seem relevant in my case.

How should I go about troubleshooting this? Anyone else know of / have this problem / can think of a quick fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but just to follow up I found a way to work around this issue.

My ultimate need was to get `node` running with the package [`resemble`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resemble) installed. Resemble relies on `cairo`, which was installed via homebrew; it seems that this was my first mistake. Because Cairo was apparently improperly installed, a couple packages were missing; this forced me to use one workaround that triggered other errors and required other workarounds... and so forth.

When I removed the Cairo homebrew package and instead built Cairo from source (using [this guide](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/installation---osx)), several other errors I was having just melted away.

So the lesson I'm learning is: Don't use Homebrew for anything finnicky, or for any *dependencies* of anything finnicky.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by this:

```
rm /usr/bin/npm
/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install npm -g
npm -v # success !
```